# Xcode 7 crash every time I try to print something in the debugger console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I've searched around and can't find anything on this.

Using Swift 2 and Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001). Every time I execute something in the debugger console, Xcode crashes.

The project is not very big, and has less than 10 third party frameworks.

I can't think of much more information that's relevant, but I'm sure there's more, so please do ask me if there's anything I should add to my question that would help.

I've of course cleaned build and derived data.

It's driving me insane. Thanks!

**UPDATE 16/11/12**

Submitted [rdar://23559366](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5004595382190080).

Comment: What do you mean? Missing from being included in the target? A Cocoa Touch framework that a third party frameworks depends on is missing?? All the third part dependancies use module maps to declare their dependancies, and I've confirmed that they're all included properly in the targets.

Comment: If the frameworks are Obj-C, do you have a bridging header file and did you import the right header in there? although this would give you a compile error when u access the frameworks in your code.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, along with xcode crashing whenever I try to use the Debug View Hierarchy tool. I tried all the normal paths to fixing bizarre crashes (delete prefs, clean + build), and as a hail mary deleted my (empty) bridging header file. None of my attempts did much...

Comment: Same problem for us in 6.4 and now 7.1. Radar?

Comment: @RobertAtkins updated with Radar :)

Comment: Mine is rdar://23380303.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you maintaining your third party frameworks? Via Carthage?

If so then this is probably your issue: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/924

This is an issue if the location of the /Carthage/Build/iOS folder is in a different location to where it was produced (i.e if it was compiled on a different machine and the absolute file path has changed).

A temporary fix would be to run `carthage build --no-use-binaries` on your machine to rebuild the symbols using the current absolute file path working around the bug.

But if you wasn't using carthage then its probably not your issue so sorry

Comment: Xcode was crashing everytime I would trigger the Debug View Hierarchy and running `carthage build --no-use-binaries` solved it for me.

Tip: I appended `--platform iOS` to the previous command to avoid building for all platforms :-)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Xcode whenever I hit breakpoint.

[image]

In case you see this screen right before your Xcode crashes - you are lucky and my fix might save you. All you need to do is open this window and in the Project Navigator, select any file that you want, so that instead of that white blank view you would get your code. After this you are most likely will be able to successfully stop your app at your breakpoint and perform the debug.

I am not sure why this happens, but I suspect that the reason is Debug View Hierarchy mode, which you might have triggered prior to setting you breakpoint and trying to stop at it. At least this is when it happens to me.

Comment: Please include the solution in your answer instead of an external link. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what happens in my case. I see my code when Xcode hits a break point, I then type something in the debugger console and hit enter, it thinks for a second or two, and .

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem earlier. 
If you try to print non-optional variable and unfortunately it holds nil value then it breaks/crash. so that make sure declare all possible variables as "Optional type".